# Getting error : No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, ms-access

Below Is my Update query ,it was working fine,but when I have added `int DrId` in parameter fields (at last) to check where condition,after this it is showing me following error

`No value given for one or more required parameters.`
where is the mistake ,since `DrId` is my Primary Key I won't update it

```
public bool UpdateDrMaster(string title, string FirstName, string Mname, string lastName, string regNo, string speciality, string contactNo1, string contactNo2, string city, string addrss, string pincode, string emailId, string fee_unit, string fee, string DrType, bool displayType,int DrId)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            try
            {
                string sql = "UPDATE Doctor_Master SET [Title]=@Title,[FirstName]=@FirstName,[MiddleName]=@MiddleName,[LastName]=@LastName,[RegistrationNo]=@RegistrationNo,[Speciality]=@Speciality,[ContactNo_1]=@ContactNo_1,[ContactNo_2]=@ContactNo_2,[City]=@City,[Address]=@Address,[Pincode]=@Pincode,[Email_ID]=@Email_ID,[Fee_Unit]=@Fee_Unit,[Fee]=@Fee,[Type_of_Dr]=@Type_of_Dr,[Display]=@Display,[Hide_Date]=@Hide_Date WHERE Doctor_ID=" +DrId;

                cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, acccon);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", Mname);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastName);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationNo", regNo);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Speciality", speciality);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo_1", contactNo1);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo_2", contactNo2);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", city);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", addrss);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pincode", pincode);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email_ID", emailId);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fee_Unit", fee_unit);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fee", fee);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type_of_Dr", DrType);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Display", displayType);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hide_Date", System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());                            
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                flag = true;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
            }
            return flag;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `Doctor_Id` in your Update query but you are not setting a value for it. Even though you are not going to update its value you have to set a value for it as its part of your where clase.

```
string sql = "UPDATE Doctor_Master SET [Title]=@Title,[FirstName]=@FirstName,[MiddleName]=@MiddleName,[LastName]=@LastName,[RegistrationNo]=@RegistrationNo,[Speciality]=@Speciality,[ContactNo_1]=@ContactNo_1,[ContactNo_2]=@ContactNo_2,[City]=@City,[Address]=@Address,[Pincode]=@Pincode,[Email_ID]=@Email_ID,[Fee_Unit]=@Fee_Unit,[Fee]=@Fee,[Type_of_Dr]=@Type_of_Dr,[Display]=@Display,[Hide_Date]=@Hide_Date WHERE Doctor_ID=" +DrId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try this one!!! Replace you parameter name with ?

```
 public bool UpdateDrMaster(string title, string FirstName, string Mname, 
    string lastName, string regNo, string speciality, string contactNo1, 
    string contactNo2, string city, string addrss, string pincode, string emailId, 
    string fee_unit, string fee, string DrType, bool displayType,int DrId)
            {
                bool flag = false;
                try
                {
                    string sql = "UPDATE Doctor_Master SET Title=?FirstName=?,
    MiddleName=?,LastName=?,RegistrationNo=?,Speciality=?,ContactNo_1=?,
    ContactNo_2=?,City=?,Address=?,Pincode=?,Email_ID=?,Fee_Unit=?,Fee=?,
    Type_of_Dr=?,Display=?,Hide_Date=? WHERE Doctor_ID=?";

                    cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, acccon);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", Mname);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastName);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationNo", regNo);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Speciality", speciality);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo_1", contactNo1);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo_2", contactNo2);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", city);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", addrss);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pincode", pincode);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email_ID", emailId);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fee_Unit", fee_unit);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fee", fee);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type_of_Dr", DrType);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Display", displayType);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hide_Date", System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()); 
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrId", DrId);                           
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    flag = true;
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
                }
                return flag;
            }
```

### Another Possible reason

Match your Db column name with the queries column. See if any character is misplaced or miss-spelled

Comment: No everything is right ,after adding where condition it is showing me error ,before it was working