# error : No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to Fetch Id by comparing `dataetimepicker's`  `month and year value` with date stored in database column of type `Date/Time`,Below is Query I am using to do this but it is showing me following error at this line `while (rs.Read())`

**error**

```
No value given for one or more required parameters.
```

**Code**

```
public int GetDrID_MonthWise(string DrName,int month,int year, int refDrID)
{
    int data = 0;
    try
    {
        string sql = "Select d.DoctorID From Doctor_Master d,Patient_registration p where d.LastName + ' ' + d.FirstName = '" + DrName + "' AND datepart(mm,p.[RegDate])=@month AND datepart(yyyy,p.[RegDate])=@year AND p.DoctorID=" + refDrID;
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, acccon);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", month);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year);
        rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rs.Read())
        {
            data = Convert.ToInt32(rs[0]);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
    }
    return data;
}
```

I am passing month and year values like this ,Where I am doing mistake ?

```
int month = dateTimePickerMonth.Value.Month;
int year = dateTimePickerMonth.Value.Year;
```

Comment: what about other values in the where part? Maybe DrName or refDrID are starting with @

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197022/getting-error-no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is mistake in your query, please do like this,

```
 string sql = "Select d.DoctorID From Doctor_Master d,Patient_registration p where d.LastName + ' ' + d.FirstName = '" + DrName + "' AND datepart("m",p.[RegDate])=@month AND datepart("yyyy",p.[RegDate])=@year AND p.DoctorID=" + refDrID;
```

**Note:** You have to enclosed date interval with "" in DatePart function in ms access and only single m for month. If you didn't enclosed yyyy and m with "", system supposed that yyyy and m are parameter and expected value for these parameter.

> If you execute your query in Ms-Aceess sql view then it will show this
> message "Enter Paremeter Value".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a error in your Query,
see there is no equal to sign for lastname column

```
where d.LastName + ' ' + d.FirstName = '
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check 3 issues

> - Check this int month = dateTimePickerMonth.Value.Month; int year = dateTimePickerMonth.Value.Year; values are not null or empty
> - The date and time is a datetime datatype , so why you assign this value in integer ? So It's converted to different format .
> - And your d.LastName column value is null , If you give the  empty values ,then try
>   this way

```
d.LastName = '"+ string.Empty + " ',.. .....
```

Do check these conditions and try again .

Answer (score 0):

Or Simply Make Correction in string

```
sql = "Select d.DoctorID From Doctor_Master d,Patient_registration p where d.LastName + ' ' + d.FirstName = '" + DrName + "' AND Format(p.[RegDate],mm)=@month AND Format(p.[RegDate],'yyyy')=@year AND p.DoctorID=" + refDrID;
```